# Look for cookie of external site then redirect

Tags: jquery, cookies, ning

I have a ning network. i have also got a custom homepage which is just a html/css site.
What I need is a script to detect if they have previously visited my ning site and are logged in. If not they don't get redirected.
Any thoughts would be great.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't read cookies from a different domain (i.e. a page at stackoverflow.com can't read cookies set by microsoft.com) - it's a pretty obvious security feature. See [this article on quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html#link5) for more info. If you're using a different domain for your homepage than your ning site, then you're out of luck.